# Need for classification - but no need for prediction

Tags: classification

I have a project where our customers are interested in classifying data (binary classification). Data set is very small and feature space is very large (p>>N).
If I use a technique - for example like Random Forest which is supposed not to overfit the data, is there a need to test the predictability of the model?

Comment: You need to tell them what to expect, right?  How could you do this without testing?

Comment: They were only interested in just classification which is coming out very well with low error rate. What am I adding extra when I test the model? especially for techniques such as Random Forest whose claim to fame is that it doesn't overfit? I am ambiguous whether to test or not. I am inclined towards using test data and checking how well it predicts. But then if model performs well on all the data without overfitting can't this be taken as is?